# unable to install 'dplyr', 'lubridate', packages in R Studio

Tags: installation, package, rstudio, dplyr, permission-denied

I am trying to install "dplyr", "lubridate" , "sqldf" packages in R Studio..
but am getting the below error in the end.

**Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'D:/R/R-3.2.2/library/file1e28658e7173/Rcpp/doc/Rcpp-attributes.pdf': Permission denied**

i have reinstalled both R and R Studio but still getting the same error.
(and as you may have noticed i have installed R , R Studio in D Drive to avoid issues with C Drive.. 
but the packages themselves are downloaded in C Crive first.. is there anyway i can download these packages in D Drive and then install/load them).

Can anyone pls suggest how to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: But i am able to load packages like ISLR..

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I got the solution (Thanks to my friend Arjun!)

1. Just download each dependency package (folder) and manually paste it in the R Library (in my case for example in 'C:\Users\487063\Documents\R\win-library\3.2')
2. then load the package from R (not R Studio)
3. Go back to R Studio and try loading 'dplyr'

the problem is that R keep throwing one error at a time for each dependency so the above steps have to be repeated again and again till the whole package (dplyr) is installed

Same for other packages like SQLdf etc